# DDR3 SDRAM specification understanding

Tags: hardware-rec, ddr, sdram

What's difference between two memory modules `4GB 2Rx8 PC-10600S-09-10-D1` and `4GB 2Rx8 PC-10600S-09-10-F2`. What the ending is stand for? I wonder if those modules could work together.

Comment: Do you know the manufacturer and part number? Those numbers by themselves mean nothing without knowing more specifics. That being said, they both seem to be 4GB DDR3 PC-10600 modules with what APPEARS to be similar timings, they should work together. Even if the timing capabilities are different, the motherboard should use the slower one's settings and both should work together. I would not hesitate to plug them in (properly per MB manufacturers recommendations) and test it.

Answer (score 0):

This difference in nomenclature most likely has to do with differences in the manufacture of the RAM - whether it is single or dual rank, for example. In some cases, this matters, but for daily use (and even in most workloads), this doesn't really matter.

As acejavelin said, I'd not hesitate to try them out together. They may even be able to run in dual-channel mode.